# Restrict a user to running a command only two times

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to restrict a user to run a command only two times in Ubuntu.

Specifically, I have created a custom command through an alias which needs to be executed only two times by every user.

My custom command is

```
alias extend_shutdown_150='bash extend_shutdown.sh 150'
```

I'm not getting the way to implement more on this!

---

```
#!/bin/bash
minutes=$1
echo $minutes >> /usr/bin/input.log

a=`grep -i 15 /usr/bin/input.log | wc -l`
b=`grep -i 30 /usr/bin/input.log | wc -l`
c=`grep -i 60 /usr/bin/input.log | wc -l`
#echo $a $b $c
if [[ "$a" -gt "2" ]] ||  [[ "$b" -gt "2" ]] ||   [[ "$c" -gt "2" ]] ; then
     echo " Error: User tried to snooze the system more then 2 times"
elif [[ "$minutes" -eq "15" ]] ||  [[ "$minutes" -eq "30" ]] ||   [[ "$minutes" -eq "60" ]] ; then
     echo " System shutdown is extend $minutes Minutes more"
else
  echo " Error: Minutes must be one of 15,30 or 60"
fi
```

So based on user input the data will be stored into `/usr/bin/input.log` so I'm comparing the same file to stop the user from snoozing the system.

Is there any possible way I can append the username & date in `/usr/bin/input.log` e.g.:  `hari 9/2/2021 15`?

Comment: which command? why would you want to limit them to 2 times?

Comment: I have created a custom command through alias which needs to executed only two times by every user and its my requirement. Please help me.

Comment: Could that custom command not keep a log of who ran it and how many times, then present an error to the user on excessive operations? It's already custom, so why not customise it further? 

Comment: my custom command is "alias extend_shutdown_150='bash extend_shutdown.sh 150". I'm not getting the way to implement more on this!

Comment: I know of no existing command with such built-in logic for you to use. You must create it.

Answer (score 1):

You may implement that yourself in your bash script.

- Have the script log the date and user in a log file each time the command is started.
- Have the script read the log and check whether the date/user combination occurs less than twice (e.g. a `grep -c $PATTERN $FILE` could do: this counts the number of lines in which a certain pattern, e.g. "date + username", occurs)
- Continue execution or halt with a message if the number of lines > 2.

Comment: I suppose that, instead of piping to `wc`, you can use the `-c` option in `grep`. Is it correct?

Comment: That is even better, of course. Will change it, with thanks.

Comment: How to add this "Have the script log the date and user in a log file each time the command is started."..?

Comment: Aren't you into bash scripting already?

Comment: i'm into bash scripting